# How to get the description of a command without running it, using its name?

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

If I use a command like this one:

```
class ImportFilesCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('A text describing my command.')
            ->setName('app:import:files')
            );
    }
```

Is it possible to get the description *'A text describing my command.'* using the name of the command `app:import:files`, without executing the command?

I would use this inside a controller.

Comment: Is it getting the description "by the command name" a hard requirement? What do you mean precisely by "without executing the command"? You can certainly get the name without calling `execute()`, which is what actually runs the command.

Comment: @yivi yes I meant without calling `execute()`. I found the answer thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

This code works from a controller:

```
$application = new Application($this->get('kernel'));
$description = $application->find('app:import:files')->getDescription();
```

Comment: just to be clear, this will instantiate the command to get the name, if you're looking for a lazy way of getting the name this is not it.